# initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: objective-c, iphone

here is the code, where listArray is NSMutableArray
......

```
listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i ++ )
            [listArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

....

```
for(int max=99; max >= 0 ; max --)
{
    int rN = (arc4random() % max) + 0;

    //Warning 1: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
    int temp = [listArray objectAtIndex:rN];
    [listArray insertObject:[listArray objectAtIndex:max] atIndex:rN];

    //passing argument 1 of 'insertObject:atIndex:' makes pointer from integer without a cast
    [listArray insertObject:temp atIndex:max];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "unbox" the int value:

```
int temp = [[listArray objectAtIndex:rN] intValue];
```

The array stores objects (here an `NSNumber`), while you want a plain `int`.

The same holds for insertion, that's why you call `[NSNumber numberWithInt:...]` while adding.

Edit: The indices in the array range from 0 ... (count-1), not sure if your `+1` does what it should.

Comment: He never actually uses the unboxed number, so I see no reason to unbox then rebox.

Comment: true, but the code doesn't make much sense anyway, so I thought it was more of a code example for the method invocation and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
NSNumber *temp = [listArray objectAtIndex:rN];
```

NSMutableArray holds Obj-C objects, which is why you have to use `NSNumber numberWithInt:`.  That means when you pull it out with `objectAtIndex`, you get a `NSNumber *`.